# AmCharts: How to make balloon follow mouse & chart cursor?

Tags: html, graph, charts, line, amcharts

I successfully consolidated the data from multiple line charts into one balloon. I still got to use SOME graph to position the balloon though. I do not want this. I want the tip of the balloon to follow the mouse. I have seen this somewhere before, i just cant remember where...

[I FOUND HOW IT SHOULD LOOK :D](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q55TK.jpg)

Additionally, i would like the balloon to update. Meaning that if a graph is dismissed via legend, the balloon-info should only show the remaining graphs and the other way around.

Please help me.

Max

Comment: @martynasma any ideas? I heard you know about these things ;)

Comment: There's no way to make the balloon follow the cursor. It will always stick to the bullet. To make the balloon display only visible graphs, look into `graph.balloonFunction` http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#balloonFunction

Comment: I played around a little bit and that's what i got working: http://jsfiddle.net/tjp7jh0o/ It's still not perfect, because it always switches back to the real position first.

Comment: @gerric i had thought about doing it that way. All i would need now is to be able to have a balloon that is completely uncoupled from the graphs. I think it would work then. Thanks for you input! :)

Comment: @MaximilianM. So you're ok with not using the amCharts balloon? I did this a while ago. Just added a new div element to show the values.

Comment: @gerric Could you rapidly make an example? I cant quite follow :P

Comment: @MaximilianM. take a look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/8cgt6Ltn/). Problem is the vertical movement. The event handler is only called if the cursor is moved horizontally. You would have to use the mousemove event.